# Store NSHttpCookie in iOS Keychain Using Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, keychain

I have an authentication token received from a web service in the form of an HTTP cookie. Currently I am relying on iOS's default behavior of storing cookies returned from HTTP requests in the `NSHTTPCookieStorage` object which persists the cookies until the user closes the application.

However, I would like to persist the cookie between application lifecycles in the keychain so that when the user reopens the application, if their cookie is not expired, they will not need to login again. It does not seem there is an easy way to store generic objects into the keychain, so it seems the best route is to serialize the dictionary object retrieved via `NSHTTPCookie`'s `property` to a string and store that in the keychain. I can then rebuild the cookie via `initWithProperties` constructor in `NSHTTPCookie` and stick it back in the `NSHTTPCookieStorage` object.

What is the easiest way to do this in Swift? I found code Apple wrote called "KeychainItemWrapper", but the documentation for it is pretty spotty and it seems that it was made for storing user's emails (or usernames) and passwords, more than generic objects. Is there an easier way to work with the keychain, or a better way to safely store the web service's authentication token?

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that some cookies will have properties that are not directly serializable. For example, "Expires" is expressed as _NSTaggedDate, which cannot be serialized directly. As such, you will need to convert it into a string or integer representation first, and do the reverse when deserializing.

Answer (score 2):

### Update iOS 14 and above

The function `unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(_:) is deprecated since iOS 13 but it was not warning until iOS 14. There are few new functions e.g` unarchivedObject(ofClasses:, from:)`,` unarchivedObject(ofClass:, from:)`... In order to adopt HTTPCookie with those new functions, we need to make it confirm to` NSSecureCoding`.

Fortunately, when looking at https://github.com/ForgeRock/forgerock-ios-sdk I figured out a way to achieve that:

```
final class SecureHTTPCookie: HTTPCookie, NSSecureCoding {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        var properties = [HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]()
        let version = coder.decodeInteger(forKey: "version")
        let name = coder.decodeObject(of: NSString.self, forKey: "name") as String?
        let value = coder.decodeObject(of: NSString.self, forKey: "value") as String?
        let expiresDate = coder.decodeObject(of: NSDate.self, forKey: "expiresDate") as Date?
        let isSessionOnly = coder.decodeBool(forKey: "isSessionOnly")
        let domain = coder.decodeObject(of: NSString.self, forKey: "domain") as String?
        let path = coder.decodeObject(of: NSString.self, forKey: "path") as String?
        let isSecure = coder.decodeBool(forKey: "isSecure")
        let isHTTPOnly = coder.decodeBool(forKey: "isHTTPOnly")
        
        let comment = coder.decodeObject(of: NSString.self, forKey: "comment") as String?
        let commentURL = coder.decodeObject(of: NSURL.self, forKey: "commentURL") as URL?
        let portList: [NSNumber]?
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            portList = coder.decodeArrayOfObjects(ofClass: NSNumber.self, forKey: "portList")
        } else {
            portList = coder.decodeObject(of: [NSArray.self, NSNumber.self], forKey: "portList") as? [NSNumber]
        }
        
        let sameSitePolicy = coder.decodeObject(of: NSString.self, forKey: "sameSitePolicy") as String?
        
        properties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.version] = version
        properties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name] = name
        properties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value] = value
        properties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain] = domain
        properties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path] = path
        properties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.secure] = isSecure ? "TRUE" : nil
        properties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.expires] = expiresDate
        properties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.comment] = comment
        properties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.commentURL] = commentURL
        properties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.discard] = isSessionOnly ? "TRUE" : nil
        properties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.maximumAge] = expiresDate
        properties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.port] = portList
        properties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey("HttpOnly")] = isHTTPOnly ? "TRUE" : nil
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            if let sameSitePolicyValue = sameSitePolicy {
                properties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.sameSitePolicy] = HTTPCookieStringPolicy(rawValue: sameSitePolicyValue)
            }
        }
        
        super.init(properties: properties)
    }
    
    static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    init?(with cookieProperties: [HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]) {
        super.init(properties: cookieProperties)
    }
    
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.version, forKey: "version")
        aCoder.encode(self.name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encode(self.value, forKey: "value")
        aCoder.encode(self.expiresDate, forKey: "expiresDate")
        aCoder.encode(self.isSessionOnly, forKey: "isSessionOnly")
        aCoder.encode(self.domain, forKey: "domain")
        aCoder.encode(self.path, forKey: "path")
        aCoder.encode(self.isSecure, forKey: "isSecure")
        aCoder.encode(self.isHTTPOnly, forKey: "isHTTPOnly")
        aCoder.encode(self.comment, forKey: "comment")
        aCoder.encode(self.commentURL, forKey: "commentURL")
        aCoder.encode(self.portList, forKey: "portList")
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            aCoder.encode(self.sameSitePolicy, forKey: "sameSitePolicy")
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
func setCookies(_ cookies: [HTTPCookie], for url: URL) {
        guard let storeKey = storageKey(for: url) else { return }
        do {
            let secureCookies = cookies.compactMap { $0.properties }.map { SecureHTTPCookie(with: $0) }
            let cookiesData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: secureCookies, requiringSecureCoding: true)
            secureStorage.set(value: cookiesData, forKey: storeKey)
        } catch {
            print("Fail to archive cookies to data: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func getCookies(for url: URL) -> [HTTPCookie] {
        guard let storeKey = storageKey(for: url),
              let cookieData = secureStorage.get(key: storeKey)
        else { return [] }

        do {
            let cookies = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass: SecureHTTPCookie.self, from: cookieData)
            return cookies ?? []
        } catch {
            print("Fail to unarchive data to cookies: \(error)")
            return []
        }
    }
```

## Old approach for iOS 12 and below

I believe any Keychain's 3rd lib provide the `Data` storing method ([KeychainSwift](https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift#data-values), [KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess#for-nsdata))

The missing part is how to turn `[HTTPCookie]` into `Data` and vise versa. Fortunately, the `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` come to the rescue.

Here is the code I'm using in my application to set / get the cookies with keychain:

```
    func setCookies(_ cookies: [HTTPCookie], for url: URL) {
        guard let storeKey = storageKey(for: url) else { return }
        do {
            // Convert [HTTPCookie] to Data
            let cookiesData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: cookies, requiringSecureCoding: false)
            keychainStorage.set(value: cookiesData, forKey: storeKey)
        } catch {
            print("Fail to archive cookies to data: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func getCookies(for url: URL) -> [HTTPCookie] {
        guard let storeKey = storageKey(for: url),
            let cookieData = keychainStorage.get(key: storeKey)
        else { return [] }

        do {
            // Convert Data to [HTTPCookie]
            let cookies = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(cookieData) as? [HTTPCookie]
            return cookies ?? []
        } catch {
            print("Fail to unarchive data to cookies: \(error)")
            return []
        }
    }

    private func storageKey(for url: URL) -> String? {
        guard let host = url.host else { return nil }
        return "CookieStorage.\(host)"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout SSKeychain: https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain. It has a really nice and usable interface over the keychain API's.

It's not Swift per se, but you should still be able to use it in a swift app. I don't think there's a way to store objects themselves, but as you mentioned you can serialize the cookie into a string and save it in the keychain.

Example below for how it could be used.

```
NSString * const LoginService = @"com.example.loginService"; // unique identifier shared across your apps to identify various services your app may provide that require the keychain

NSString *cookie = // cookie string
NSString *userAccountIdentifier = // could be an email, username, id, or some other way to uniquely identify the user

[SSKeychain setPassword:cookie forService:LoginService account:userAccountIdentifier error:&error];
```

Comment: What do the `service` and `account` variables mean in the documentation? Is the service my application? Then what is the account? It seems a little unnecessary to use an open source library - is this really the established solution to using the keychain in swift?

Comment: Added a short example for how it could be used. The `service` and `account` are really just arbitrary strings that your apps use as a key to various data stored in the keychain. Unfortunately, there aren't any Swift specific frameworks that I know of to interface into they keychain. Really your choices are: use the raw Keychain API's (which are really hard to use), copy Apple's keychain wrapper (which isn't that much better), or use an open source library.

Comment: Well thank you for the example. I will definitely give it a shot.